# BST intersection, NullPointerException

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a new BST from the intersection of 2 known BSTs. I am getting a NullPointerException in the intersect2 method int he second case, at the line  "cur3.item.set_account_id(cur1.item.get_accountid()+ cur2.item.get_accountid());". I know you get the error when you try to dereference the variable without initializing it but i think i am initializing it? I'm not really sure. I would appreciate the help.

```
public static Bst<Customer> intersect(Bst<Customer> a, Bst<Customer> b){
     return( intersect2(a.root, b.root));
 }

  public static Bst<Customer> intersect2(BTNode<Customer> cur1, BTNode<Customer> cur2){
  Bst<Customer> result = new Bst<Customer>();

// 1. both empty -> true
  if (cur1==null && cur2==null){
  result=null;
 }
// 2. both non-empty -> compare them
 else if (cur1!=null && cur2!=null) {
  BTNode<Customer> cur3 = new BTNode<Customer>();
  cur3.item.set_account_id(cur1.item.get_accountid()+ cur2.item.get_accountid());
  result.insert(cur3.item);
  intersect2(cur1.left, cur2.left);
  intersect2(cur1.right, cur2.right);
 }

// 3. one empty, one not -> false
else if (cur1==null ||cur2==null){
  BTNode<Customer> cur3 = new BTNode<Customer>();
  cur3.item=null;
  intersect2(cur1.left, cur2.left);
  intersect2(cur1.right, cur2.right);
}
 return result;
}
```

Here is the image of the problem: [image]

Comment: why not just do `Bst<Customer> intersection = new Bst<Customer>(); for(Customer c : a) if(b.contains(c)) intersection.add(c);`

Comment: I'm sorry But I don't follow what you are trying to say. My aim is to create a third tree by adding the nodes at the levels where both the given trees have children. The element of the new tree is decided by adding one of the attributes of the Customer object.

Comment: So, if both trees have the same Customer, but it's on the third 'level' of three a and the fourth 'level' of tree b, it wouldn't be included in your intersection?

Comment: If tree a has only 3 levels then the result tree will only have 3 levels. The customer on the fourth level of tree b will only be taken into the calculation if tree a also has at least 4 levels. Does it make a little more sense now?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why does the internal location of the element in the tree matter for the intersection? The user of the tree should not know (or care) where in the tree the elements are, just that they exist and that they can be retrieved in a reasonable (in this case, lg n) time.

Comment: how can I share an image with you on stackoverflow? Maybe a pictorial representation of what I am trying to do will help. I could be doing this wrong and would appreciate it if you know of a smarter/easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NullPointerException can be caused by a number of things. In your given example, cur1 and cur2 are not null, but there is no guarantee that cur1.item, cur1.item.accountId (and similarly for cur2) are not null.

Being as you have no description for the underlying implementation, I cannot assist further.
I can suggest that you do some of a few things: 
1.) check the implementation of your objects (if this happens EVERY time, there may be some sort of initialization problem. 
2.) Whenever you create an instance of your item, do you make sure to specify the accountId field? Try giving a default value for this field so it cannot be null. (try some sort of illegal value [eg -1, false, etc] and test for it.

If you would post more implementation details, I (or someone) may be able to directly identify the problem.

Regards.

Edit:4/20@17:11
Here's an example of what you should be doing.

```
public class Customer {  
    private int accountId;  

    public Customer() {  
        this.accountId = 0;  
    }  

    public Customer(int account_identification) {  
        this.accountId = account_identification);  
    }  

    //As a side note, general practice implies fields be private  
    //Use a method (hence the term 'getter' and the reciprocal, 'setter')  
    public int getId() {  
        return this.accountId;  
    }  

    public void setId(int replacement_account_identification) {  
        this.accountId = replacement_account_identification;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, The customer class has a default constructor that does not set values to anything. It's just an empty constructor. The BTNode Constructor sets the values of the item and it's left and right nodes to NULL. Does this information help?

Comment: Yes, as you are not initializing the accountId field (implied by an empty constructor), you are trying to concatenate/add a potentially null value. This is a no-no. The left/right nodes being null is alright (it's actually "correct") so no problems there. It seems you should (at the very least) generate/define a default value for accountId.

Comment: I initialized the accountId in the default constructor to 0 but the error is still there.

Comment: Lol I can't believe I didn't see it... cur3.item.set_account_id.... Here cur3 has no item. Make an item (Customer) for it and the problem (should) go away. Right before the problem line, take the item out of one of the other nodes, place it in cur3, and update the account.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to figure it out. Thanks for your help, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the item variable in Customer object is not initialized.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on that?

Comment: ie. item member of cur3 might be null. ie cur3.item = null.

Answer (score 0):

Does creating a BTNode automatically allocate its member `item` ?

You do:

```
cur3.item.set_account_id(.. )
```

For this to succeed, both `cur3` and `cur3.item` need to be not null.

Same applies to `cur1` and `cur2` as well, that you reference later in that line.

And the example of the 3rd case shows that BTNode.item can be null in some scenarios:

```
cur3.item=null;
```

Comment: Creating a BTNode initializes the member item to null. I do that in the third example because I don't want any value for that node (it will be any empty node aka does not exist) in the resultant tree. Is it wrong to do it this way?

Comment: Yes. item==null will create the NPE, as cur3.item.set_account() does dererference (cur3.item), which is null, so ends up with null.set_account(). Same for the other BTNodes as well.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how to fix this? As far as I can see that step is necessary because the new tree's node's  item needs to be assigned the value. Should i assign cur3 to the result's root node? I don't really know if this would be the ideal solution either as the root itself is decided through the method. I;m sorry I am just confused and stuck at this point.